# How can I conditionally prefix a key in i18next?

Tags: typescript, internationalization, i18next

We are consolidating i18n backends together and in the process the localization keys get prefixed with `ModuleA`, `ModuleB`, ... `ModuleFoo`

We are rolling this out in a fragmented way, based on the language and culture, so the people responsible can control when to do the switch. This can take many weeks and based on a condition we want to prefix all keys with the module name in question. My idea was to overwrite the `t` function of i18next conditionally.

I am running into syntax errors in typescript right now and have hit a wall:

```
export const createI18N = async (language: string, country: string): Promise<I18N> => {
    const i18nLang = `${language}_${country.toUpperCase()}`;

    if (instances.has(i18nLang)) {
        return instances.get(i18nLang) as I18N;
    }

    const instance = baseInstance.cloneInstance();

    
    const originalT = instance.t.bind(instance);

    instance.t = (key, opts) => {
        const prefix = "moduleFoo.";
        const shouldPrefix = true;

        const prefixedKey = shouldPrefix ? `${prefix}${key}` : key;
        return originalT(prefixedKey, opts);
    };

    await instance.changeLanguage(i18nLang);

    instances.set(i18nLang, instance as I18N);

    return instance as I18N;
};
```

```
Property '$TFunctionBrand' is missing in type '<Key extends string | TemplateStringsArray,
 TOpt extends TOptions, Ret extends TOpt["returnObjects"] extends true ? $SpecialObject :
 string>(key: string | Key | string[] | Key[], opts: string | ... 2 more ... | undefined)
 => TFunctionReturnOptionalDetails<...>' but required in type 'TFunction<["translation", ...string[]], 
undefined>'.ts(2741)
```

What am I doing wrong here or is there a more suitable approach to this?